# How to automatically retry Apache connection to application server if it returns 503?

Tags: apache

I have an Apache server set up as a reverse proxy to an application server that works fine generally.

However I would like to set it up so if the application server returns unavailable 503, then Apache waits 1-2 seconds and then retries again.

Note - the retry parameter in the documentation refers to caching of the 503 response and how long before checking the app server is back up (not in the same request).

All I can find is something called setRetryHandler but it's over my head and I'm not sure how to use it (seems to be in the apache source code perhaps).

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an easy task, as mod_proxy is doing what it's told to do (and designed to do), which is deliver the right message from the backend.

You can work around this, I believe, by using a "holding page" on the frontend which redirects. To achieve that, you should set `ProxyErrorOverride` to On, and have 503 errors redirected to a holding page with `ErrorDocument 503 /some_holding_page`, then have that page be either a html page with some refresh mechanism, or a script that sleeps for 1-2 seconds and then redirects back to the page that caused the error.